# How can I get Aws RDS ARN through tags?

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-rds

I want to get RDS ARN through tags.

Actually I want to add a tag to an RDS that already has a specific tag. and start or stop rds.

The tag I want to add is rdsonly:true by payload

```
import boto3
rds = boto3.client('rds')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    #Start DB Instances
    dbs = rds.describe_db_instances()
    for db in dbs['DBInstances']:
        #Check if DB instance stopped. Start it if eligible.
        if (db['DBInstanceStatus'] == 'stopped'):
            try:
                GetTags=rds.list_tags_for_resource(ResourceName=db['DBInstanceArn'])['TagList']
                for tags in GetTags:
                #if tag "autostart=yes" is set for instance, start it
                    if(tags['Key'] == 'autostart' and tags['Value'] == 'yes'):
                        result = rds.start_db_instance(DBInstanceIdentifier=db['DBInstanceIdentifier'])
                        print ("Starting instance: {0}.".format(db['DBInstanceIdentifier']))
                        response = client.add_tags_to_resource(
                            ResourceName='string',
                            Tags=[
                                {
                                    'Key': 'string',
                                    'Value': 'string'
                                 },
                                ]
                        )

            except Exception as e:
                print ("Cannot start instance {0}.".format(db['DBInstanceIdentifier']))
                print(e)
                

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lambda_handler(None, None)

But don't know how to put ResourceName ARN

Thank you for your advises
```

Comment: dbs['DBInstances'] also contains  'DBInstanceArn', you can use it (db['DBInstanceArn']) to add new tags.

Answer (score 1):

In every case for boto3, when you "list" or "describe" resources you will get back the individual resource ARNs embedded in the response payload.  You will just need to reference the response payload [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.describe_db_instances).  The pertinent part is:

```
'DBInstanceArn': 'string',
```

As Vishal mentioned in the comments, you can reference this in your code with something like:

```
db_instance_arn = db['DBInstanceArn']
```

Or via a direct reference in the "add_tags_to_resource" call.

```
response = client.add_tags_to_resource(
    ResourceName=db['DBInstanceArn'],
```